# Search string using Regular expressions

Tags: c#, .net, regex, algorithm

I am using C# and I am completely new to Regular expressions. I have learned about the basic operators like `+ * ? \d` etc. The problem is that suppose I am given a string like:

> C:\Users\Pratik\Desktop\abc.txt

I want to use Regex to search through the part of the string after the last '\'. ie "abc.txt" only. 
Currently I am using this mechanism:-

```
    string input = @"C:\Users\Pratik\Desktop\abc.txt" ; 
    string[] inputSplit = input.split('\\');
    int length = inputsplit.Length ;
    Regex.isMatch(inputSplit[length-1], pattern) ; 
   // pattern is any pattern you want to search for.
```

Is there any more effecient way to do it using Regex?
Since, people have given me another solution of `Path.GetFileName(input)`.
I have tried to measure the time taken in executing the above task using both `GetFileName` method as well as the above mentioned code and here are the results :

`My method: 3323 milliseconds`
`Path.GetFileName: 1763 milliseconds`.
`after using Regex: 2563 milliseonds`

So,`Path.GetFileName(input)` is the most efficient solution out of these 3 solutions.

Comment: Why Regex? There are much easier ways..

Comment: `Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Users\Pratik\Desktop\abc.txt")` - returns `abc.txt`

Comment: Use last index of `\\` with string.substring, and you're done ...

Comment: `Path.GetFileName` is the way to go, unless it is a very performance-intensive application. It reads better, more robust, less stuff to test, etc...

Comment: @Noctis `Path.GetFileName` does "exactly" that (except it handles strings like `a/b/c`, `a\b\c` and `c:`), just fire up `ILSpy` and open `mscorlib/System.IO/Path/GetFileName(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference on using a regex:

```
string input = @"C:\Users\Pratik\Desktop\abc.txt";
string pattern = @".*\\(.*)";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
string result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

But please, please, use the other solutions (`Path.GetFileName`)!

What `.*\\(.*)` means:

- `.*`: match any characters, note: [this is greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), meaning it will match anything up to the next regex part
- `\\`: up to a literal `\` character (you need to escape, because it's special in regex)
  (you would have to write `\\\\` if you were not using verbatim strings (`@""`)
- `(.*)` match anything after the backslash and put it into a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Thanks! I have edited the question and put up the time taken by verious methods, and certainly `Path.GetFileName` is much better.

Answer (score 2):

Not a Regex solution.. but this does what you want:

```
using System.IO;

var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

Comment: It's really fast as compared to Regex solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any more efficient way to do it using Regex?

Not sure about more efficient, I am not able to benchmark at the moment. But much simpler.

```
string input = @"C:\Users\Pratik\Desktop\abc.txt";
Match match  = Regex.Match(input, @"[^\\]+$");
Console.WriteLine(match.Value); // "abc.txt"
```

Regular expression:

```
[^\\]+         any character except: '\\' (1 or more times)
$              before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Although, I would advise to use the [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w.aspx) Class to perform on file or directory path information.

- [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)
- [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Input strings:

> C:\Users\Pratik\Desktop\abc.txt
>
> 123abc\abc\abcx

This regex

```
[^\\]+$
```

Will match

> abc.txt
>
> abcx